# How to create a new identifier by concatenating string literals?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I'd like to be able to use a `str` input as `ident` inside a macro. The specific usage would be something like this:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ( $x:ident ) => {
        let $x = "stuff";
        let $x_2 = "other_stuff"
    };
}
```

So then the macro, when called with `foo!(bar)` would create the variables `bar` and `bar_2`.
However this doesn't work, I can't find any way to modify an ident.

It seems to me this would be possible if I could transform an `expr` into a `ident`, so that I can first operate on the expression and concatenate my suffix, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that. So it would look something like

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ( $x:expr ) => {
        let to_ident!($x) = "stuff";
        let to_ident!(concat!($x, "_2")) = "other_stuff"
    };
}
foo!("bar"); // creates variables bar and bar_2
```

Comment: You can't do this in a declarative macro.

Comment: Rust explicitly disallows this in declarative macros: identifiers are meant to be sanitized, thus all created identifiers should be passed in from the calling context. If you want to do this, use a [procedural macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) instead.